# Como mudar logo ao rolar scroll no navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento, nav-bar

Oi gente vejam se podem me ajudar, preciso de uma função usando jquery ou um método mais simples, que mude meu logo ao rolar o scroll do mouse, no momento, eu tenho a seguinte função, que apenas altera a cor do navbar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()){
            $('nav').addClass('color');
            $('logo').attr('src', '/img/logo-dark.png');
        }else{
            $('nav').removeClass('color');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Logo abaixo tenho o html com o logo fixo nesse navbar:

```
 <nav>
    <div id="logo" class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/logo-branco.png"></a>
    </div>
```

No caso, toda vez que descesse o scroll igual na cor da navbar, mudasse o logo para o logo que está no local src="img/logo-dark.png"

Comment: Se alguma resposta lhe serviu marque-a como aceita. Veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o script que usei em umas das minhas páginas

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('.navbar').css("background-url", "dist/img/logo1.png")
        } else {
            $('.navbar').css("background-url", "dist/img/logo2.png")
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Precisa usar o seletor correto na linha:

```
$('logo').attr('src', '/img/logo-dark.png');
```

O seletor acima está incorreto e não irá selecionar nada. O seletor correto poderia ser:

```
$('#logo a img').attr('src', '/img/logo-dark.png');
```

> `div` com `id #logo` que possui a tag `a` e que possui a tag `img`.

Ou:

```
$('#logo').find("img").attr('src', '/img/logo-dark.png');
```

> `div` com `id #logo` que irá buscar tags `img` dentro de si.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal colocar um id na imagem

```
<img id="image"....
```

e no script

```
$('#image').attr('src',.....
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()){
        $('nav').addClass('color');
        $('#image').attr('src', 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-SAd3nVaqjlE/Tzci2PpZGLI/AAAAAAAAPx4/erFXdQl5MfY/s1600/facebook-wallpaper-celular-papeis+(16).gif');
    }else{
        $('nav').removeClass('color');
    }
})
```

```css
#enchelinguissa{
height:1200px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <div id="logo" class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img id="image" src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/avatar_5933d8570bff_128.pnj"></a>
    </div>
    
    
    <nav>
    <div id="enchelinguissa">Essa div e o css não fazem parte da resposta.
 É só para dar scroll para testar o "executar"</div>
```